# jQuery UI Auto-Complete: Menu does not show up

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-3, autocomplete

I'm trying to use an auto-complete widget that gets its data from a remote source via an AJAX request. The data should be coming as a JSON result of the `GetDistricts` Action Method on the AddressController. Unfortunately, the menu does not pop-up when I type into the text box. I checked the response in Firebug and everything seems okey:
`{"districtNames":["Beirut","Bekaa","Mount Lebanon","South","Nabatieh","North"]}` so I do not really know what's going on... Here's my jQuery code:

```
            district.autocomplete({
                minLength: 2,
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: '@Url.Action("GetDistricts", "Address")',
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.text,
                                    value: item.text
                                }
                            }))
                        }
                    })
                }
            });
```

And here's my action method:

```
    public ActionResult GetDistricts(string term)
    {
        var districts = _service.GetDistricts();
        var districtNames = from c in districts select c.Name;
        return Json(new {districtNames}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

P.S: I tried it with local data where the source is an array and it worked just fine. So I do not think it's something to do with CSS...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your results array from the controller action is not in the format that the widget expects.  Autocomplete expects an array of strings (or an array of objects with `value` and `label` properties), not an object with a single property who's value is an array of strings.

You could fix this by updating your controller action:

```
public ActionResult GetDistricts(string term)
{
    var districts = _service.GetDistricts();
    var districtNames = from c in districts select c.Name;
    return Json(districtNames, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

If you took this route, you might even be able to get away with removing lots of your `$.ajax` code and let autocomplete take care of it:

```
district.autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: '@Url.Action("GetDistricts", "Address")'
});
```

---

Or you could massage your data just a bit inside the `$.ajax` `success` callback:

```
district.autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetDistricts", "Address")',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data.districtNames, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.text,
                        value: item.text
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

*Note* that `$.map` is called with `data.districtNames`.

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker: Yeah I changed the way I'm sending back the data from the action method. It worked okey and the menu popped up. But I could not select an item. It keeps throwing this error: `f.item is null`. Could that be a bug in the auto-complete widget itself or what?

Comment: @Kassem: Interesting--are you still defining the `source` as a function, or are you just using the url to your controller action?

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker: Just the url to the controller action. When I tried to define the source as a function, the menu popped up "empty". I checked the `ul` tag in firebug, and all the `li` tags had nothing inside them. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Kassem: Hmm, not sure--It seems like a pretty straightforward use of the widget. Did you get this error when using a local data source (like a JS array)?

Comment: @Kassem: Also, if you can reproduce it in http://www.jsfiddle.net, I'd be happy to take a look :)

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker: It was a problem with the CSS. I had a `display:block !important;` on the ui-autocomplete class. Therefore, it was always being displayed. Thanks for the help, appreciated :)

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker: By the way, when getting the data from a remote source, do I get all the data or do I filter (on the server-side) on the term entered into the text box?

Comment: @Kassem: You'll want to filter on the server-side. If you want to let the widget do the filtering you could render all the values into an array inside your view, then pass that to the widget.

Comment: This answer solved my problem, but not in the way I expected. I'd been trying "jsonp" because it seemed that was the only type of json supported based on the documentation, but after seeing your example, I tried changing to straight "json" just for the heck of it, and it worked! Gracias!